# User.last_login not populating as expected in Django test

Tags: django, django-models

Why is `user.last_login` `None` in the following test:

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client


class TestModels(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username="testUser", password="testPassword"
        )
        self.auth_client = Client()
        self.auth_client.login(username="testUser", password="testPassword")

    def test_user_last_login(self):
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.user.id)  # pull the latest data
        print(user.last_login). # <-- this is None, why?!
        self.assertIsNotNone(user.last_login)
```

I am clearly logging in, then querying the user from the database to refresh the data.

Comment: When you use `User.objects.create` it does not _hash_ your password. So `login` is actually returning `False` and the user isn't actually logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_login` is not updated because you are not logging in. All User passwords are encrypted, so when you are creating user like that, his password will be in plain text and you won't be able to authenticate by it. To create User with enrypted password, change

```
self.user = User.objects.create(
            username="testUser", password="testPassword"
        )
```

to

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="testUser", password="testPassword"
        )
```

and your tests will pass

Comment: Oh right I completely forgot about `create_user`! Thank you